# A question on spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in {C^{n \times n}}$ and ${\sigma (A + B)}$ is spectrom of $(A+B)$.

Suppose

- $M = \left\{ {\lambda  \in C:\lambda  \in \sigma (A + B),\left\| B \right\| \le \varepsilon } \right\}$
- $F(A) = \left\{ {{v^*}Av:v \in {C^n},{v^*}v = 1} \right\}$
- $K = \left\{ {\lambda  \in C:dist(\lambda ,F(A)) \le \varepsilon } \right\}$ ,where ${dist(\lambda ,F(A))}$ denotes the distance between $\lambda $ and 
  $F(A)$.

Why does $M \subseteq K$?

Comment: Please consider asking at Mathematics StackExchange instead. (This smells like homework, which is typically not what we entertain here.) Be prepared in that case to explain to them what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lambda  \in M \Rightarrow \exists v: (A+B-\lambda E)v=0 $. Without loss of generality we assume that $\|v\|=1  $.

Then $v^*(A+B-\lambda E)v =0 \Rightarrow \|v^*Av - \lambda\|=\| v^*Bv
\|.$

Then you need to show that last expression is less than $\varepsilon$ and you will have that  $\lambda  \in K$.